# Firebase Authentication Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

During Firebase Auth set up on my React project.
I am not able to make to make Auth Pop up trigger on button click.

Either it throws an error inside the console after button click OR it automatically opens Authentication after refreshing the page
(Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.)

```
// Initialize Firebase
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
const config = {
  apiKey: "myKeyHere",
  authDomain: "domain",
  databaseURL: "url",
  projectId: "idb",
  storageBucket: "bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);

export default firebase;
```

### And Here is my Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import signInWithGoogle from "../../firebase";

    class Header extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <nav className="header">
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in</button>
          </nav>
        );
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => state;

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

As you see the Sign In button should trigger signInWithGoogle arrow function from Firebase , but it throws an error onClick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are importing the default export from '../../firebase', which is 'firebase' instead of the sign in function.

To fix that you just need to add curly brackets {} to the import so that you import the named export instead of the default:

```
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../firebase";
```